# TimSort : Optimal Algorithm for identifying natural runs within a given single block

Tags: algorithm, sorting, timsort

Question :   How does timsort identify during chunking or generating runs of block size [32-64 items] that the most optimal approach is to search for ascending or descending run ?

```
Known Fact : A run in timsort is a natural occurring sorted order of data items [ either ascending or descending ].
```

Example : Assume an array which has block size of 6 for sorting. A block of 6 encountered in the array of data provided is as follows.
Further assume that the array is being sorted in ascending order.

```
arr = {..............7, 11, 9, 6, 5, 2, ..................}.
```

If we see the hint provided by first two items 7, 11 this is increasing subportion of the run.
At this point considering next 4 items to ensure that we maintain or look for a increasing run would be inefficient since its actually a decreasing run [ 9, 6, 5, 2 ].
A binaryInsertionSort algorithm would sort this in increasing order like below.

7

7, 11

7, 9, 11

6, 7, 9, 11

5, 6, 7, 9, 11

```
Result=2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11---------(A)
```

In fact the most efficient method would have been.

7, 11 -> A complete ascending run.

9, 6, 5, 2 -> A complete descending run.

merge ([ 7, 11 ], [9, 6, 5, 2])

merge([7, 11], [2, 5, 6, 9]) //in place reversing of second array.

```
Result=2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11 -------(B)

Fact: (B) is more efficient then (A) from computing perspective.
```

**Question:**

Does Tim sort actually do (A) or (B) for a given block of size 
[ Ex:- 32 to 64 items ].
i.e until the block size is met does it identify progressively looking at 
each item and performing binaryInsertionSort of each item to build the sorted Run ?

or

does it actually scan the whole block first to identify already occurring 
natural sorted sub sequences to merge them efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does (A). [Identify the next run](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6989af0bc7ea1e9a1acea16794e6f723d7b44110/Objects/listobject.c#L2369-L2370) and then [if short, extend it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6989af0bc7ea1e9a1acea16794e6f723d7b44110/Objects/listobject.c#L2375-L2379) with [binary insertion sort](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6989af0bc7ea1e9a1acea16794e6f723d7b44110/Objects/listobject.c#L1197-L1209)